# What is the name of the process of folding faces into 3D objects?

Tags: geometry, 3d, computational-geometry

What is the name of the process of folding a series of 2 dimensional faces into a 3 dimensional shape by calculating their vertex positions, given a list of vertices which connect with each other?

I imagine this as being the process of taking a paper craft shape and folding it into shape.

Comment: This may-or-may-not be what you want, but knowing the term might help you in searches:: ["polyhedral net"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(polyhedron)).

Comment: Looks very close. I am trying to work out how to fold a shape as defined similar to: http://cdn.acidcow.com/pics/20091112/cat_papercraft_04.jpg I will continue reading, but is this what polyhedral nets can be used for?

Comment: It's hard for me to say. Nets are certainly unfolded polyhedra, and there's been combinatorial research on how many distinct nets can be made from a given polyhedron, etc. Papercrafting is more-specifically like "polyhedral nets with tabs". Google-searching that phrase might get you closer to the information you need. If you *have* a polyhedral figure (like that cat) and want to know how to convert it to a net-with-tabs for papercrafting purposes, then: I have only a very-vague recollection of there being an automated utility (or at least an algorithm) for that kind of thing somewhere.

Comment: Well, I sure would love that link. I've been searching all day. Perhaps my google-fu is not what it was.

Comment: This might be what I was thinking-of: Check out the [Stella](http://www.software3d.com/Stella.php) software. (The web site looks ancient, but the last update was only(?) two years ago.) The documentation discusses exporting nets (with tabs!), but I don't know how well it all works (or how hard it is to model something like a polyhedral cat in the first place). It's probably worth a look. (If the software is unusably out-dated, then perhaps you can use the name to search for alternatives.)

Comment: I believe this might be what you need: [Pepakura Designer](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/pepakura-en/) converts 3D models into unfoldable patterns. You have to create the models in a separate program, though. It's Windows-only, and I'm Mac-only, so I don't know how well it works for what you want to do. I will say, though, that I first saw Pepakura "in action" in [this video from Tested.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZ4Ph5V_LQ8), wherein they make giant papercraft heads from photogrammetric data. (Obviously, you have a different starting point, but the video may still be instructive.)